# Do not retrieve rows where only the first column is populated and rest are empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-sheets-api

I have a very unique problem that I was curious to see if there is a workaround. Google API has the ability to ignore empty rows and retrieve only rows with data in them. Is there a way for it to say ignore a column during that check but still retrieve them?

I have looked at the google sheets api and tried used rows and columns . The other option I have done is retrieve all the rows and just now show the empty ones (this is slow cause I retrieve 100,000) and initially ignore most of it (over time all of them will be filled hopefully).

```
/**
 * Prints the names and majors of students in a sample spreadsheet:
 * @see https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/edit
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth The authenticated Google OAuth client.
 */
function listMajors(auth) {
  const sheets = google.sheets({version: 'v4', auth});
  sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
    spreadsheetId: '1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms',
    range: 'Class Data!A2:E',
    majorDimension: "ROWS"
  }, (err, res) => {
    if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
    const rows = res.data.values;
    if (rows.length) {
      console.log('Name, Major:');
      // Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
      rows.map((row) => {
        console.log(`${row[0]}, ${row[4]}`);
      });
    } else {
      console.log('No data found.');
    }
  });
}
```

```
-------------------------
|S.No| Name | Created   |
| 1  |   A  |01/12/2012 |
| 2  |   B  |05/12/2012 |
| 3  |      |           |
| 4  |      |           |
```

The result should be only  rows 1 and 2 and ignore 3 and 4 since the name is not yet populated. But I end up getting all 1,2,3,4 when I call the api.FYI I do still need the S.No for rows that are being retrieved (Cant just ignore it)

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? About ``The result should be only rows 1 and 2 and ignore 3 and 4 since the name is not yet populated.``, how do you get the result? In your script, I think that "1, 2, 3, 4" of "S.No" can be retrieved, while ``row[4]`` will be ``undefined`` because the column "E" is not declared in your sample input. By the way, if you want to achieve it using Node.js, please modify the tag.

Comment: The table is to drive the point. The real table has more than 2 columns. Also will add the tag.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your issue. So can you provide the detail flow for replicating your situation?

Comment: So in my scenario the user will input data in the form but not the S.No . He will also have a table view showing the data he has entered. The S.No column is something that will be pre-populated in the sheet and when data is entered by user it will be added to from col[1] to col[4] and the table will be refreshed where we now will show the user the complete row. The trick is I do not want user to see a list of rows with 
col[0] populated and nothing else .

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, from your comment, I cannot see the vision about your goal, yet. When I could see it, I would like to think of your solution. I'm sorry for this situation.